# How to know how many active online games currently

Tags: android, google-play-games

Since the concept of listing rooms available or in progress is not available in Google play game services, how can I (as a developer) know how many game rooms are in progress (multiplier games happenong)?

This is very important to know if this multiplier feature is actually working for my users and they sre able to find players and matches. Please advise

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such facility available within the API. You can ping your own server each time a game starts from the client side. That can give you a running count of active/completed games.